# How to automate logging into a router from a gateway switch and running commands inside the router

Tags: cisco

I work in an environment where i have to log into multiple routers and get basic bgp , interface details etc. Unfortunately these routers are only accessible via logging into a gateway switch and then entering my username and IP of the router ,after which password entry prompt comes and i enter the password to log in to the router and get all the details.

I used paramiko to automate this and was so far able to log into the gateway switch and send commands. unfortunately im not able to get the correct code to log into the the router from the switch and give the password and show commands. Is this possible and if so how ?

Any help on this will be appreciated. Thanks

The below is the code i use to log into the switch

```
import paramiko
import getpass
import time

Host = "10.163.3.185"
username = "a2201471-3"
password = "ToW4Tj@7+u+z#FS"

ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()

ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

ssh_client.connect(hostname=Host, username=username, password=password)

print("Seccessfully Connected\n")

remote_connection = ssh_client.invoke_shell()
remote_connection.send("terminal len 0\n")
remote_connection.send("ssh -l gark_mnsey 10.162.248.47")  ## this is the 

command which i mannually type inside the switch to get the password prompt of the router.





time.sleep(1)

output = remote_connection.recv(18999).decode('ascii')

print(output)

ssh_client.close
```